# Getting Image From Android to Unity3D

Tags: unity, android-studio

I am trying to get an image from the user gallery and import it in unity. I have written a native plugin in Android Studio and exported JAR as it’s needed for the native stuff to get working. I am successful in opening gallery but I don’t have an idea how do I get that image retrieved from OnActivityResult in Java File and use it in C# for Unity.
Any help and ideas will be highly appreciated.